# How to get the query string from the URL

Tags: php, apache

Even if I give different URL, my php application is redirecting to the default page. That too before I'm going to get that URL from the application.

I want the query string and the actual url, which has been clicked by the user. But my application is giving the URL of the default page.

How can I get the actual URL and query string?

Comment: You're question is rather unconcrete, so probably start with reading the manual, e.g. here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Slightly o/t but very useful for you, try this: `<?php print_r($_SERVER) ?>` - lots of great environment vars for you to use :)

Comment: use `print_r($_SERVER);` to check other options.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] // query
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] // full URL
```

will do that

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```